# ! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined

Tags: miktex, latex-base, chngcntr

After updating MikTex up to 09.04.2018 (MikTex 2.9.6637, Win 10, 64bit) I've got the error:

```
(F:\...\texmfs\install\tex\latex\chngcntr\chngcntr.sty
! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                               
l.42 ...thout}{\@ifstar{\c@t@soutstar}{\c@t@sout}}                                                  
?
```

It seems to me this problem is connected with multiple definitions of star versions od `\counterwithout` / `\counterwithin` in latexrelease.sty and  chngcntr.sty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Is anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Something that has changed recently and it made it's way into MikTeX already?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes there have been three latex releases in last three days, but also `latexrelease` is mostly aimed at end users not core developers.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's not really clear from the documentation, in my point of view.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer well it is only for running old documents on new formats (or the other way round) so it is just for fixing local issues with locally available documents.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wonder how many documents are broken then until `chngcntr` is updated unless your work-around isn't applied.

Comment: @samcarter Sorry for a stupid question but what's mean "MWE"?

Comment: @Alexey Please see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @samcarter Thank you,  we already have found a solution.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer update gone to ctan this morning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If `counterwithin` and `counterwithout` are now defined in latex, does that mean `chngcntr` is not neccessary anymore? (I am not sure if I understand everything of this discussion here correctly.)

Comment: @Lysanne if you have the very latest latex it is not necessary but you may want to leave the package in for a while as it does not harm and makes things work in "old " latex (which includes current texlive releases, as the new latex release is just in the texlive 2018 pretest which is not for general use)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Since I just migrated to TeXlive two days ago this is good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A new version 1.1a of `chngcntr` is now available on ctan which detects that the commands are already defined and so does nothing other than leave a message in the log, so the error in the question is no longer generated.

---

**Original answer**

For now, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

`chngcntr` needs a small update (which was planned but the current maintainer is possibly distracted at present)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but, unfortunately, in my document chngcntr.sly are loading implicitly as a part of some package (which I don't know).

Comment: @Alexey put the two `\let` lines as the first two lines of your document, that should work also

Comment: The оnly solution I've found is to replace  \newcommand\counterwithout  by  \renewcommand\counterwithout within chngcntr.sty

Comment: @Alexey you should not change inside packages. And a better solution would have been `\providecommand` instead of `\renewcommand`, then the version coming from LaTeX wins.

Comment: @daleif Of course, I shouldn't but it's the quickest solution than I can find.

Comment: @Alexey are you using miktex "next" or a standard miktex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is the small update required for the `chngcntr` package? As the originator of the package I might do something but better the current distracted maintainer.

Comment: @PeterWilson Hi, one possible suggestion is [here](https://github.com/davidcarlisle/chngcntr)  Will was planning an update before the release but... Basically we adopted the package into the format so chngcntr (and my even older `remreset`) are obsolete in the new  format, if you are happy with the suggestion on that githib and send me an email to authorise a ctan  update I could push it to ctan, or if you would rather do it I'm happy to delete that again:-)

Comment: @PeterWilson I got a quick message from Will so I'll update ctan later, hope that's OK

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I trust you and Will better than I trust myself now. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Maybe that helps someone who had problems getting the updated version to work: For me, the error remained even after installing the updated version of `chngcntr` and also after deleting all document generated files and recompiling and after explicitly calling the package version. The error pointed to the `chngcntr.sty` in the AppData/Local/Roaming tree. So I had to delete the old file there to make LaTeX use the new updated version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just installed TL2018 (Win-64) and stumbled upon this question and your answer. I see, that ctan lists chngcntr 1.1a, but `tlmgr update --all` does not fetch it (chngcntr.sty says: 1.0a). Do you have an idea why? And how I could get the updated version (using tlmgr)? Thx!

Comment: @lAtExFaN oh thanks for the ping. I see same here I guess texlive team busy moving things over to tl2018 and it got missed, I'll ask on texlive list

Comment: @lAtExFaN the new package is distributed by tlmgr today (or possibly tomorrow if your mirror is slow to catch up)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes I've already updated and tested it successfully - thanks for your report!

Comment: [The fixed package on CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr.zip)