# Latest MacTex install will not compile old 'tex' files that used to work?

Tags: counters, mactex

Now Using MacTeX-2018 
Getting this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

Found this solution, on stack exchange
[! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425600/latex-error-command-counterwithout-already-defined/425603#425603?newreg=631d93c323604c83b52fed022905826c)
which recommends you do this ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
\usepackage{chngcntr}
```

But that does not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us a short document that reproduces the error, please? Refer to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864 for guidance on preparing an MWE. You may also want to include `\listfiles` at the very top of your document and report the file versions as reported at the end of the `.log` file. An update (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864) might just solve your problem.

Comment: Have you also run TeX Live utility on your installation to update all the packages? This document compiles without problems for me (with or without the `\let` commands.  But the error you show is not from that document.

Comment: `\counterwithin` and `\counterwithout` have been moved to the latex core, `chngcntr` should have been updated to accommodate, it would be useful to get a full log. And as Alan mentioned, you should always update MacTeX after installing it (MacTeX is a snapshot in time, so it does not have the updates that have come out since this MacTeX version came out)

Comment: 1. moewe I will add a 'tex' file shortly 
2. Alan Munn, No.  I did not run the Tex Live utility, I downloaded the package this morning.  I will do so next thing.  
3. I will attach the log

Comment: You possibly have a rogue copy of `chngcntr.sty` somewhere in your path. Can you look in the log file for it?

Comment: OK.  I do not understand.  I moved the suggested fix to the VERY top, ...
[answer]
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  %% <- LINE 1
\let\counterwithout\relax %% <- now here
\let\counterwithin\relax
\usepackage{chngcntr}

%%\usepackage{ERGTN-SAMPLE-2017/ntarep}
\usepackage{ntarep}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{ERGTN-SAMPLE-2017/GMLRS_SW_glossary} % path to GLS Acronym Definitions
\glsdisablehyper
[answer]
and now it compiles.  Not understanding this, as I do not think it should matter.

Comment: egreg, I did that when the error first cropped up, prior to going to stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.  I would appreciate it if someone would explain why the location of 

\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax

matters

I also need to learn how to format. My comments are a mess.

Comment: clearly you need to undefine the commands before they are redefined so the position matters, but if you have the current version of `chngctr` then you do not need `\let\counterwithout\relax` at all

Comment: @noStepOnSnake on code in comments, don't do that, instead edit the question and add code there in a code block (`{}` button) so line endings preserved)