# ! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithin already defined

Tags: memoir

I just reinstalled my MikTeX 2.9, and am getting this following error message:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithin already defined.
>                Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
> ```

I saw the following line of questions in this link:
[! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithout already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425600/latex-error-command-counterwithout-already-defined) but it doesn't seem to be my problem, as I checked and the `chngctr` version is 1.1a.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\let\counterwithout\relax
\let\counterwithin\relax
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

This information is duplicated directly from the Blahblah.  

%The above is necessary in order to display the subsections in the TOC.
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
    lalalal

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mine MikTeX 2.9 compiles it without errors, even with `\let` lines commented.

Comment: Maybe you have a local version of `chngcntr.sty` that takes precedence over the version you checked. Have a look at the `.log` file to find out where the `chngcntr.sty` is found and what its version is.

Comment: @moewe, thank you, I looked at my .log file and this is the only line that references chngcntr:  "Package chngcntr [2008/07/23] emulated by memoir. "  Is this my problem?

Comment: That probably means you need to update `memoir` as well. What version do you have? I have no problems with v3.7g, 2018/04/04. At least my version of `memoir` uses `\providecommand{\counterwithin}` and `\providecommand{\counterwithout}` which should not be a problem. But I'm not sure about older versions.

Comment: Check logs for local copies of memoir, check the path for memoir. It probably says app data, and thus was not deleted when you reinstalled miktex. Remember miktex (confusingly) installs in two places, system and user. The latter takes precedence, this is why every time you update miktex you have to update as user and admin, or you end up with old user versions overwriting new system versions.

Comment: Thank you.  I am using memoir 2016/05/16 v3.7f .  I'll update it.  Also thanks for clarifying that miktex installs in two places, I was confused.  I'll check this too.

Comment: It's working now, thank you everyone!  I deleted the memoir in my user location and reinstalled the memoir package.  Now everything is working as it should.  :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after a reinstallation mentioned in comments the issue vanished.